# Django file explorer

Tags: django, static

I need to create a Django file explorer. It needs to perform a similar function to the Simplehttpserver that comes with python. The main purpose is rendering static HTML files and making certain directories available for TEST users or ITOPS users etc. Need some advice on how to do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.